# Google OAuth Client Library for MS Graph authentication

Tags: integration, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, google-oauth-java-client

So I've been working on Google OAuth Client Library to integrate MS teams. I suppose that Google OAuth client library can be used for any OAuth Services on the web.

But is there any documentation / code flow explaining how this library can be used for this integration ?

Comment: Check this [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/microsoft-teams-auth/) and see if the options for Google oAuth works for you or not.

Comment: @Foo Please let us know does the above help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Dev comments

Obtain OAuth2 client credentials from the Google API Console. Enable access to the Google People API.

Follow the remaining steps provided in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/microsoft-teams-auth/).